# How to get Formcollection values in the get method of an action in a controller in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I m displaying data in a grid after clicking a button. In the grid value of sort attribute is true.
So the problem is when i press the link in the grid to sort a particular column or next page then it is calling to the get method of that action and result is none. How can i acheive this????
Thanks in advance....

Comment: You will get the `sort` as querystring to your controller. By using sort value you should be doing sorting on grid. [Check this link](http://www.elylucas.net/post/Using-a-grid-that-can-sort-page-and-filter-in-AspNet-MVC3e28093Part-1e28093Using-the-WebGrid-WebHelper.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It wont be in the `FormCollection` cause you are not posting data.  Have a look in the `QueryString`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult NewUser(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    String roleValue1 = formCollection["inputRole"];
}
```